# Solar panel specification

Tags: solar-cell

I am planning to buy a small solar panel where it is specified that it produces 6V and 100mAh. So does this means that the solar panel will produce 100mA in 1 hour or will it produce 100mA straight away as the sunlight hit the panel.

The panel size is 7 * 7 * 0.3 cm and it is made of polycrystalline.

Comment: It might be worth spending some time reading up on solar cells and the distinction between current vs current times time.  Stack exchange sites are really meant for what is left *after* consulting references, not as a substitute for them.

Comment: It would appear that both the dimension and the "100mAh" are typos, either in your question or in the seller's promotional materials.

Comment: What kind of load will you be using it for?

Comment: Taken literally, it means that over the lifetime of the solar panel, it produces 100 mAh. Whether that's 100mA and it dies after 1 hour, or 1 mA and it dies after 100 hours, is anybody's guess. Practically, it's a garbage specification. Buy the product at your own risk. It may even produce 100 mA in full sunshine, hour after hour, for years. At 7 x 7 cm, producing 0.6W is reasonable but not great efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, solar panel specs are given for mostly **S**tandard **T**est **C**onditions *(i.e. under 1kW/m² sunlight intensity, at 25°C ambient temperature, etc)*.

> it's specified that it produces 6V ...

This is probably the open-circuit (i.e. unloaded) voltage generated by the solar panel. This voltage is the maximum voltage that can be measured under STC.

> ... and 100mAh.

mAh is a unit of charge - \$\mathrm{Q = i \cdot t}\$ thus \$\mathrm{Coulomb = Ampere \cdot hour}\$ and is not a parameter for a solar panel. At least, for ones that I've seen <sup>If there's a solar panel with charge specification, please someone let me know</sup>. Instead, solar panels have short circuit current specification which indicates the maximum current that can be drawn under STC. So, the product that you are interested in has built-in battery-like storage <sup>(I don't think so)</sup> or there's a typo <sup>(Most likely)</sup>.

---

PS: I agree with what @Chris says. Googling "how to read solar panel specs" can bring you lots of info.